# How to move vertexes uniformly?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I have a half a cilinder which I want to modify uniformly to 2 concave sides on it. How can I move all the vertexes on one side in a uniform maner to create this shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want using the "Proportional Editing" in Edit Mode.

[image]

See how it works on YouTube: [Demo Video](https://youtu.be/55mR3tXH-kg)

Note: you can change the effect range (gray circle) by using mouse wheel (which is broken at my mouse...)

Comment: Use the Smooth setting in this case and just select one centre vertex on the curve. I'd also set the transform pivot point to 3D Cursor, set the effect range to around half the diameter of the circle, and then scale inwards (using Shift-Z if it's a cylinder rather than a circle). I can do a full answer if required.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for it for so long, somehow all the google answers where for more complicated tasks.